# POST data to WEB API formatted XML instead of JSON results in 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: json, xml, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017, restsharp

The Details of my project are here : [WebApi Parent Child POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46430051/web-api-entity-framework-parent-child-posting-to-sql-database/46473269#46473269)

My current issue is that if I try to POST as XML instead of JSON running the WEB API in DEV mode through VS 2017, I get a 415 Unsupported Media Type error from the POST command.  The XML Data looks like this:

```
<Borrowers>
  <Borrower>
     <FirstName>Ima</FirstName>
     <LastName>Pepper</LastName>
     <MiddleName>O</MiddleName>
     <SSN>555-55-5555</SSN>
  </Borrower>
  <Borrower>
     <FirstName>Ura</FirstName>
     <LastName>Pepper</LastName>
     <MiddleName>J</MiddleName>
     <SSN>555-55-555</SSN>
  </Borrower>
</Borrowers>
<ClientCode>cc1</ClientCode>
<Contacts>
  <Contact>
     <Email>j@test.com</Email>
     <Fax>414-222-1245</Fax>
     <Name>Jackie</Name>
     <Phone>414-555-1243</Phone>
  </Contact>
</Contacts>
<CostCenter>900-777</CostCenter>
<FileNumber>777</FileNumber>
<LoanAmount>777</LoanAmount>
<LoanNumber>777</LoanNumber>
<Notes>notes1</Notes>
<OrderID>15</OrderID>
<PID>1</PID>
<PayOffLoanNumber>po1</PayOffLoanNumber>
<Product>letter</Product>
<Properties>
 <Property>
     <Address>8888 W Lake Pointe Dr</Address>
     <City>Franklin</City>
     <County>Milwaukee</County>
     <State>WI</State>
     <Zip>53132</Zip>
  </Property>
</Properties>
<ResponseURL>yahoo.com</ResponseURL>
<ToBeInsured>true</ToBeInsured>
```

I have tried numerous suggestions related to Content Type and accept:

```
Content-Type: application/xml
accept: application/xml
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
```

with no success.

My Global.asax.cs file is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace wsEtitle
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Re    ferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove    (GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        }
    }
}
```

and my WebAPIConfig.cs file looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace wsEtitle
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

what is also confusing is the response header that comes back suggesting it was expecting JSON:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 721
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 28 Sep 2017 15:51:59 GMT
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Aspnet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Sourcefiles: =?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNcZG91Zy5oYW1pbHRvblxkb2N1bWVudHNcdmlzdWFsIHN0dWRpbyAyMDE3XFByb2plY3RzXHdzRXRpdGxlXHdzRXRpdGxlXGFwaVxPcmRlcnM=?=
```

Not sure what I am missing at this point.

Comment: I commented out the last line in the Global.asax.cs file related to "removal of the XML formatter.

Comment: Got a different error:  400 BAD REQUEST 

`<Error>
    <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
    <ExceptionMessage>Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entity</ExceptionMessage>
    <StackTrace>at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName) at System.Data.Entity.DbSet'1.Add(TEntity entity) at wsEtitle.Controllers.OrdersController.Post(Order order) in C:\Users\Doug.Hamilton\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\wsEtitle\wsEtitle\Controllers\OrdersController.cs:line 64</StackTrace>
     </Error>`

Line 64 is the Add of the Order